# Extract recursivly multiple line data between two String- Regex & Python & XML

Tags: python, regex, xml, parsing

I have a huge XML file from which I need data for specific entries. File structure is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE stuff>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- 127.0.0.1 -->
<opentag>
<tag1><XXXX YYYY VVV SSS></tag1>
<tag2>
<test>aaa_string_bbb_ccc</test>
</tag2>  
<debugging level="0"/>
</opentag>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE >
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- 192.168.10.1 -->
<opentag>
<tag1><DDD FFF BBB></tag1>
<tag2>
<test>zzz_number_yyy_xxxx</test>
</tag2>
<debugging level="0"/>
</opentag>
```

In my XML i have many of these entry.
What I have to achieve is to extract all the lines (complete record) for certain entries.
I need to create different xml file, one for every times that you found text between 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
 till next 
`</opentag>`.

In this case i would like to have tow different xml file, with different file name. Ex :

1  -> 127.0.0.1.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE stuff>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- 127.0.0.1 -->
<opentag>
<tag1><XXXX YYYY VVV SSS></tag1>
<tag2>
<test>aaa_string_bbb_ccc</test>
</tag2>
<debugging level="0"/>
</opentag>
```

and the second one :

2 -> 192.168.10.1.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE >
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- 192.168.10.1 --> 
<opentag>
<tag1><DDD FFF BBB></tag1>
<tag2>
<test>zzz_number_yyy_xxxx</test>
</tag2>
<debugging level="0"/>
</opentag>
```

What could be the REGEX to perform such extraction of record for specific entries? 
Is there any more pythonic way to achieve this?
I would appreciate your help on this.

AS

Comment: Where did `<!-- 127.10.10.1 -->` come from?

Comment: <!-- here there are some detail about a command line executed on  specific IP addresses 127.0.0.1/16 -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use regex for this. Instead have a look at the [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module. With this, you can just iterate over all the opentags, and then write each one into a different file. This is more pythonic than using regex ('*don't reinvent the wheel*').

If you have to use regex you could do:

```
(<\?xml version="1\.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>.+?<\/opentag>)
```

Make sure to pass the `'s'` modifier so `'.'` matches newline.

This is the final solution:

```
pattern = re.compile('<\?xml version="1\.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>.+?<\/nmaprun>', re.DOTALL)
result= re.findall(pattern,data)
for item in result:
            print item
```

Comment: I can use any scripting language or any libraries. the important thing is being able to divide the xml files and produce many new xml files whenever I strings that I indicated earlier.

Comment: Your solution does not work. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: It does work. pattern = re.compile('(<\?xml version="1\.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>.+?<\/opentag>)', re.DOTALL)
result = re.findall(pattern, xmlstring) this returns a list of all the blocks.

Comment: I edited your regex raising single quotes and the script worked.
You were right !!! ;) Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the format is the same for all the files and `<!-- 127.10.10.1 -->` is actually in the first file you can use *itertools.groupby* to group the sections:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("your_file") as f:
   grps = groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.strip().startswith('<?xml version>'))
   for k, v in grps:
      if k:
          lines = list(v) + list(next(grps)[1])
          with open("{}".format(lines[2]), "w") as out:
              out.writelines( lines)
```

Which for your example data gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: I was wrong because in my XML file is not present any new line. I'm sorry

Comment: Within that comment there are the details of a command run on a IP(127.0.0.1)/subnet(127.0.0.1/20) that is launched from the terminal.

Comment: Is it always the third line of section?

Comment: yes is always the third line of the section in every section.

Comment: If i try to launch the script python return an error  on the third line.

Comment: @AndreaS., there was a typo, it is now fixed

Comment: Also with this fix the solution provided dont work :( . Maybe the best way to go forward will be to send to you a little snippet of my huge XML so you can make all the try that you wants.

Comment: Why did yo put  '<?xml> without any white space ?                          `grps = groupby(f, key=lambda x:.strip().startswith('<?xml>'))`                                                                        Are you sure that this expression match with my xml ? i am just highlighting this problem because in my XML there are another lines that begin with `<?xml...>` as can you see at the 4th line.